# localhost sent an invalid response

Tags: pixi.js

Server for PixiJS not working, "localhost sent an invalid response" error when connecting for client side

When I try connecting to the server (http://127.0.0.1:8080) through my chrome browser, I get a page which has this written on it: 
"This page isn’t working 
localhost sent an invalid response.
ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT"
And it also downloads a file called "download" with it. I have no idea as to why this happens. This "download" file is almost the exact same as the code in my index.html file. The code is the following:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Testing pixi.JS</title>
        <!--  The <script> tag's src should be relative to your root directory where your webserver is running -->
        <script src="pixi/pixi.min.js"></script>
    </head>


    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            let type = "WebGL";
            if(!PIXI.utils.isWebGLSupported()){
                type = "canvas";
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

```
<!-- MY INDEX.HTML CODE -->

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Testing pixi.JS</title>
        <!--  The <script> tag's src should be relative to your root directory where your webserver is running -->
        <script src="./pixi.min.js"></script>
    </head>


    <body>
        <h1>Hello there!</h1>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            let type = "WebGL";
            if(!PIXI.utils.isWebGLSupported()){
                type = "canvas";
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CODE TYPED INTO CMD AFTER MOVING TO SAME FOLDER AS INDEX.HTML:

npm install http-server -g

http-server

I expected the page to load but it doesn't. I have no idea as to what to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you navigate to the full path it seems to work: http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.html It seems to be some http-server [bug](https://github.com/indexzero/http-server/issues/534).

There are many other local web servers. I suggest [browsersync](https://www.browsersync.io/):

```
npm install -g browser-sync
browser-sync start --server --index index.html
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just managed to get Pixi.js to work using the express package. Thanks for the suggestion though, I'll use it as backup in case something happens to express.

Answer (score 5):

There is a bug, it seems only affect to Windows. You should install a lower version of http-server, 0.9.0 works.

Run the following command

```
npm install -g http-server@0.9.0
```

for more info click [here](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/my-server-is-running-but-i-dont-see-anything-on-the-localhost-is-anyone-having-the-same-issue).

Comment: How does this contribute over and above the already accepted answer?

Comment: Thank you for leaving this answer. I'm on Windows and I'm running into some random issue getting browser-sync to work, so rolling http-server back to 0.9.0 was exactly what worked for me. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to connect to a netgear D700 using opera and edge but got the same response.  Eventually I used the old 32bit internet explorer and got into the router.  Once the firmware was updated I was able to use opera to get into the router.